# How to retrieve parent table using child table in Gorm

Tags: postgresql, go, orm, foreign-keys, go-gorm

i'm new to Golang and facing retriving child table data that container id refer to parent table id. In the documentation shows that only the parent can retrieve child using preload method but didn't show how to retrieve reversed back.

(one to many relationship)
Parent Table

```
type User struct {
    Id           uuid.UUID  `gorm:"type:uuid;default:gen_random_uuid()" json:"id"`
    Username     string     `json:"username"`
    Password     string     `json:"password,omitempty"`
    Email        string     `json:"email"`
    Gender       string     `json:"gender"`
    Alias        string     `json:"alias"`
    RefreshToken *string    `json:"refresh_token,omitempty"`
    AccessToken  *string    `json:"access_token,omitempty"`
    DateOfBirth  *time.Time `json:"date_of_birth"`
    LastLoggedIn *time.Time `json:"last_logged_in"`
    CreatedAt    time.Time  `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt    time.Time  `json:"updated_at"`
    Account      []Account  `json:"account"`
}
```

Child Table

```
type Account struct {
    Id        uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;default:gen_random_uuid()" json:"id"`
    Name      string    `json:"name"`
    Balance   float32   `json:"balance"`
    UserId    string    `json:"user_id"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updated_at"`
}
```

Was hoping that can return json like this:

```
[{
   "Id":"xxx",
   ....
   User: {"Id":"xxx"}
}]
```

I'm not sure is this possible or not but prisma did it, sorry for disturb your time and have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

You can add which fields you want to preload and how deep to go. Check [nested preloading](https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html#Nested-Preloading).

In your case, you could do it like the below.

add `User` field to `Account` struct:

```
type Account struct {
    Id        uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;default:gen_random_uuid()" json:"id"`
    Name      string    `json:"name"`
    Balance   float32   `json:"balance"`
    UserId    string    `json:"user_id"`
    User      *User      `json:"user"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updated_at"`
}
```

in your method:

```
var users []User

// Preload Account field inside User struct, and User field inside Account struct
err := db.Preload("Account.User").Find(&users).Error
```